# What is the difference between ', ` and |, and when should they be used?

Tags: abap

I've seen strings written like in these three ways:

```
lv_str  = 'test'
lv_str2 = `test`
lv_str3 = |test|
```

The only thing I've notice so far is that ' trims whitespaces sometimes, while ` preserves them.
I just recently found | - don't know much about it yet.

Can someone explain, or post a good link here when which of these ways is used best and if there are even more ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

|...| denotes ABAP string templates.
With string templates we can create a character string using texts, embedded expressions and control characters.

- [ABAP Docu](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenstring_templates.htm)
- [Examples](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/05/17/using-new-abap-stuff-new-options-for-strings/)

Answer (score 3):

Use `'` to define character-typed literals and non-integer numbers:

```
CONSTANTS some_chars TYPE char30 VALUE 'ABC'.
CONSTANTS some_number TYPE fltp VALUE '0.78'.
```

Use `` ` `` to define string-typed literals:

```
CONSTANTS some_constant TYPE string VALUE `ABC`.
```

Use `|` to assemble text:

```
DATA(message) = |Received HTTP code { status_code } with message { text }|.
```

This is an exhaustive list of the ways ABAP lets you define character sequences.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the "when should they be used" part of the question:

`` ` `` and `|` are useful if trailing spaces are needed (they are ignored with `'`, cf [this blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/08/10/trailing-blanks-in-character-string-processing) for more information, be careful SCN renders today the quotes badly so the post is confusing) :

```
DATA(arrival) = `Hello ` && `world`.
DATA(departure) = |Good | && |bye|.
```

Use string templates (`|`) rather than the combination of `` ` `` and `&&` for an easier reading (it remains very subjective, I tend to prefer `|`; with my keyboard, `|` is easier to obtain too) :

```
DATA(arrival) = `Dear ` && mother_name && `, thank you!`. 
DATA(departure) = |Bye { mother_name }, thank you!|.
```

Sometimes you don't have the choice: if a String data object is expected at a given position then you must use `` ` `` or `|`. There are many other cases.

In all other cases, I prefer to use `'` (probably because I obtain it even more easily with my keyboard than `|`).

Answer (score 2):

Although the other answers are helpful they do not mention the most important difference between `'`and `` ` ``.

A character chain defined with a single quote will be defined as type `C` with exactly the length of the chain even **including** white spaces at the beginning and the end of the character sequence.

So this one `'TEST'` will get exactly the type `C LENGTH 4`.

wherever such a construct `` `TEST` `` will evaluate always to type `string`.

This is very important for example in such a case.

```
REPORT zutest3.

DATA i TYPE i VALUE 2.
DATA(l_test1) = COND #( WHEN i = 1 THEN 'ACT3' ELSE 'ACTA4').
DATA(l_test2) = COND #( WHEN i = 1 THEN `ACT3` ELSE `ACTA4`).

WRITE l_test1.
WRITE l_test2.
```